# PDF Form cannot be saved in LiveCycle HTML Workspace ES4 when file exceeds certain file size

Tags: pdf, workspace, livecycle

I have a PDF form in LiveCycle HTML Workspace ES4 that allows users to add file attachments and images (via image fields). If these attachments and/or images total more than 1.8 MB and the "Save" button is pressed in Workspace an "Error - Message: Null" prompt is shown and the form is not saved to the Draft folder.

The following exception is thrown:

```
2015-06-16 12:17:06,055 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-7) RuntimeException in method: public abstract java.lang.Object com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionCMTAdapterLocal.doSupports(com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.TransactionDefinition,com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.TransactionCallback) throws com.adobe.idp.dsc.DSCException:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:404)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at com.adobe.livecycle.processmanagement.services.impl.ProcessManagementTaskServiceImpl.save(ProcessManagementTaskServiceImpl.java:1622)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.component.impl.DefaultPOJOInvokerImpl.invoke(DefaultPOJOInvokerImpl.java:118)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvocationInterceptor.intercept(InvocationInterceptor.java:140)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.DocumentPassivationInterceptor.intercept(DocumentPassivationInterceptor.java:53)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(TransactionInterceptor.java:74)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.execute(EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.java:357)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.doSupports(EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor945.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:397)
    at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:233)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:173)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:378)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:181)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.process(SecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:211)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.process(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.invoke(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:650)
    at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:1092)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.BaseLocalProxyFactory.invoke(BaseLocalProxyFactory.java:436)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.StatelessSessionProxy.invoke(StatelessSessionProxy.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy321.doSupports(Unknown Source)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.EjbTransactionProvider.execute(EjbTransactionProvider.java:104)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionInterceptor.java:72)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvocationStrategyInterceptor.intercept(InvocationStrategyInterceptor.java:55)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvalidStateInterceptor.intercept(InvalidStateInterceptor.java:37)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.AuthorizationInterceptor.intercept(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.JMXInterceptor.intercept(JMXInterceptor.java:48)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.engine.impl.ServiceEngineImpl.invoke(ServiceEngineImpl.java:121)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.routing.Router.routeRequest(Router.java:131)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.rest.RestServlet.doPost(RestServlet.java:281)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.rest.InvocationFilter.doFilter(InvocationFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.adobe.idp.um.auth.filter.RestSecurityFilter.doFilter(RestSecurityFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.adobe.idp.um.auth.filter.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.internalProcess(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:74)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:599)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue with the Save functionality? The form can be SUBMITTED but it cannot be SAVED within LiveCycle HTML Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by changing the JBoss connector to accept data larger than 2MB (the default). By increasing the file size limit, forms with large images and / or attachments could be saved in LiveCycle Workspace. I also added JavaScript to the PDF form to calculate the size of all added attachments and images and limit users from exceeding the new file size limit.